# How to mention two aggregation functions in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have an sql query to get information from three different tables as following:

```
select users.username, users.id, users.avatar, users.daily_tahmin, users.alert, f1.comments_no, f2.tahmins_no, f3.monthly_tahmins_no from users LEFT join 
(SELECT count(comments) AS comments_no, user_id
 FROM comments
  Where user_id = 12
) AS f1  on users.id = f1.user_id  left join 
(
  SELECT count(tahmin) AS tahmins_no, user_id
  FROM tahminler
  Where user_id = 12
) AS f2 on users.id = f2.user_id left join
(
  SELECT count(tahmin) AS monthly_tahmins_no, user_id, matches_of_comments.match_id
  FROM tahminler
    INNER JOIN matches_of_comments on tahminler.match_id = matches_of_comments.match_id
  Where user_id = 12 AND (MONTH( STR_TO_DATE( matches_of_comments.match_date,  '%d.%m.%Y' ) ) =  '01' AND YEAR( STR_TO_DATE( matches_of_comments.match_date,  '%d.%m.%Y' ) ) =  '2014') 
) AS f3 on users.id = f3.user_id
where users.id = 12
```

and it gives the following result :

```
+------------+----+----------------+--------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------------+
|  username  | id |     avatar     | daily_tahmin | alert | comments_no | tahmins_no | monthly_tahmins_no |
+------------+----+----------------+--------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------------+
| cold heart | 12 | 1389002263.jpg |            0 |     0 |          65 |        258 |                 10 |
+------------+----+----------------+--------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------------+
```

The previous code was not optimized after i do some EXPLIAN and I tried to optimized it and I got the following query:

```
SELECT m.*,count(comments.id)
FROM comments
JOIN
(SELECT users.username, users.id, users.avatar, users.daily_tahmin, users.alert
FROM users
WHERE id=12)as m ON m.id = comments.user_id
```

My problem is that I can not get (tahmins_no,monthly_tahmins_no) every time i add them to the query it gives wrong result I can not find a way to add them correctly to the query to be in optimized way?? can I have any advice from anybody here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your simplified query is:

```
select m.*, count(c.id)
from comments c join
     users m
     on m.id = c.user_id
where m.id = 12
group by m.id;
```

You should be able to add in the monthly number:

```
select m.*, count(c.id), f3.*
from comments c join
     users m
     on m.id = c.user_id join
     (select count(tahmin) AS monthly_tahmins_no, user_id, moc.match_id
      from tahminler t join
           matches_of_comments moc
           on t.match_id = moc.match_id
      Where user_id = 12 AND 
            MONTH( STR_TO_DATE( moc.match_date,  '%d.%m.%Y' ) ) = 1 AND
            YEAR( STR_TO_DATE( moc.match_date,  '%d.%m.%Y' ) ) =  2014
     ) f3
     on f3.user_id = m.id
where m.id = 12
group by m.id;
```

The `month()` and `year()` function return numbers, not strings.  I don't understand why the field `match_date` would be stored as a string -- seems like a silly choice for a column whose name contains *date*.

Comment: it is working but the tahmins_no not added (i mean the whole tahmin_no not just the monthly)

Comment: You have to calculate that in a another subquery and add it into the query.